# Execute Multiple PowerShell Files using a SSIS Package

Tags: sql, powershell, ssis

I have multiple PowerShell script files that I need to execute in a sequential flow(one after other). Can someone please help me how to schedule multiple PowerShell files to be executed using a SSIS Package. And I need to build a fault tolerant model were I need to re-execute a powershell script in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

### Running PowerShell

There isn't a built-in Execute PowerShell task (pity) so you'll need to use an `Execute Process Task` with the path to powershell.exe

Something that you will need to take into consideration is that the default execution policy for PowerShell is Restricted which cannot run a script. Further complicating matters is the account that runs the SSIS package will also need to have its execution policy modified to be able to fire off those scripts. It's a simple matter of `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` or whatever level you feel is appropriate but you'll need to do this from within the account.

### Fault Tolerance

The simple approach is to ignore the return code in the `Execute Process Task`. Alternatively, if the desire is to keep running the PS1 until it doesn't fail, then you'd wrap a `For Loop Container` around the `Execute Process Task` and only set the terminal condition once the task returns a success value. Things might still go sideways depending on what the failure is.